# android _studio connect samsung phones.my HP laptop not connected .but other HP laptop connected

Tags: android, adb

my ***SM-G360H*** phone only not working in android studio .Not connected

[image]

Comment: Have you tried google? Have you installed ADB drivers? It's hard to answer a question like this when no background is provided. The question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have enabled debugging in Settings/Developer options.

If it is enabled then go to Device Manager and check if your phone is there, usually under other devices with a yellow triangle showing there is a problem. If so download drivers for your phone, search on the internet and restart android studio. You should be fine.